# How to test spam and bounce complaints on PowerMTA

Tags: email, powermta

I'm trying to create a system that handles spam and bounce complaints on PowerMTA, but I don't know how to simulate complaints. I'm afraid that I might mark our IP address as a spammer if I click "Report Spam" on Gmail or Yahoo to test.

In Amazon SES, I can just send an email to complaint@simulator.amazonses.com. Is there a similar tool for PowerMTA?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are great answers on this post: [Service for testing bounced email handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17699307/service-for-testing-bounced-email-handling)

Now I just have to figure out how to simulate spam complaints from the feedback loop.