# How to simulate a soft bounce situation for testing?

Tags: email, email-validation

Amazon SES has a list of [testing email addresses](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/mailbox-simulator.html) for simulating different responses, including soft-bounce. However, the address is reserved for SES, and will receive no response when called using other email service.

To simulate a hard bounce, I can simply make up some email that don't exists at all, like `no-reply@domain.that.do.not.exist`. However, is there a way to simulate soft-bounce?

Answer (score 1):

based on situations over users faced before, what seemed to work the best is using your own domains hosted at either Google or cheap shared (CPanel) hosting:
For soft bounces, set up an email account and set it to suspended.
you can check for more details in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34168517/2650584)

Answer (score 0):

You could check out the development SMTP server [MailHog](https://github.com/mailhog/MailHog). It's [Jim](https://github.com/mailhog/MailHog/blob/master/docs/JIM.md) module allows you to simulate various error conditions.

I believe the command you're looking for is `MailHog -invite-jim -jim-reject-recipient`

Comment: MailHog is something different from what's needed here.

Comment: @Snipper03 Then what is needed? MailHog Jim allows recipient failure.

Comment: Seems that this is counted as hard-bounced instead of soft-bounced.

Comment: @cytsunny Which of the [amazon SES test emails](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/mailbox-simulator.html) is accomplishes what you want?

Comment: @cytsunny Also, are you using a particular platform? If so, there may be platform specific tools we could recommend.

Comment: I am using Redhat and the ooto@simulator.amazonses.com is the one that would be counted as soft-bounced.

Comment: Hmm. I don't know (and can't seem to find) any tools that simulate auto-replies. You could probably write it with pythons debug smtp server. Here is [an example](https://avleonov.com/2017/09/14/sending-and-receiving-emails-automatically-in-python/) of some simple email processing using python. This way you can simulate anything you need, including [auto-response headers](https://www.jitbit.com/maxblog/18-detecting-outlook-autoreplyout-of-office-emails-and-x-auto-response-suppress-header/)